# Composer install OR update throw exception

Tags: composer-php

I can not make my composer install or composer update work, getting following errors.
If I ran composer install or composer update it takes long time and finally throw errors.

When I run this command:

```
composer update
```

I get the following output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                             
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out  


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Output of `composer diagnose`:

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.6.5
PHP version: 7.0.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php7.0
```

My System Configuration:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- PHP: PHP 7.0.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
- Composer version: 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:59

I have googled a lot but did not find any suitable solution for me, please help me to figure it out

Thanks

Comment: Either Packagist was down at the time, or your server is unable to reach it for some other reason (firewall, DNS issue, etc.). Try `curl https://packagist.org/packages.json` and see what happens.

Comment: @ceejayoz from above curl call, I received json response

Comment: @ceejayoz but `composer update` still failing